# Meaning of double brackets in PLY

Tags: python, parsing, formal-languages, ply

In a code using [PLY](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply) parsing package, I faced a grammar rule like this:

```
    def p_clauses(self, p):
        """clauses : clauses clause"""
        p[0] = p[1] + [p[2]]
```

what is the purpose of brackets around `p[2]`? I couldn't find anything about in the [documentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html).

**PS**: [Here](https://github.com/tulip-control/tulip-control/blob/master/tulip/interfaces/ltl2ba.py#L113) is the more complete parser code if needed. Also, [here](https://github.com/1995parham/yepc/blob/master/yepc/core/parser.py#L149) is another example which uses this syntax (It is a C parser).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer brackets and the inner brackets don't have anything to do with each other. The outer brackets do the same thing they do in a statement like `l = [1, 2, 3]`: they represent list building. `[p[2]]` builds a list whose one element is `p[2]`.

Here, `p[1]` is a list, and the assignment sets `p[0]` to a new list created by adding together `p[1]` and a new one-element list `[p[2]]`.

Answer (score -2):

p[0] is p[1] + a new list which contains p[2].